# Georeferencing vector data to another vector in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, georeferencing

I have the latest version of QGIS Las Palmas 2.18 I am trying to georeference a vector data to another.

I saw most people use VectorBender plugin but I don't seem to find it in plugins

Answer (score 1):

Go to Plugins-> Settings and activate the option "Show also experimental plugins". Now you can find and install the plugin.